# PHP error reporting suppresses AJAX error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, logging

The development server I work on had PHP errors logging turned off, so when I start a new project I add my own logging config:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_log','/var/tmp/don-errors.log');
```

With this set my ajax/php widget works perfectly.
When I remove the logging set up I get a parseerror and the famous:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

If I add just the first line back:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

The ajax JSON error goes away and everything is back to working perfectly.
 I've been searching everything I can find on what would cause the JSON error, but that's another question. I'm curious why I get no PHP errors in my PHP log with logging on, or JSON errors in console, but with logging removed I get the JSON error in the browser console and my widget dies.
I don't want to publish my widget with the logging in just to supress the error.

Here is the JSON string I'm sending back to the JavaScript as a response.

```
{"status":"success","data":{"dialogTargetId":"dialog-target-2969-212430","dialogId":"dialog-2969-212430","addBtnId":"addbtn-2969-212430","prodId":"2969","poId":"212430","dialogHtml":"<div class=\"buyer-note-dialog\" id=\"dialog-2969-212430\" title=\"Buyer Product Notes\"><div class=\"buyer-note-input\">\n\t\t<textarea name=\"buyer-note-text\" id=\"input-2969-212430\" product_id=\"2969\" po_id=\"212430\" class=\"buyer-note-text\" cols=\"35\" rows=\"3\"><\/textarea>\n\t\t<br><div style=\"padding-top: 5px\"><button id=\"addbtn-2969-212430\" emp-id=\"198\" textarea_id=\"input-2969-212430\" po_id=\"212430\" product_id=\"2969\">Add Note<\/button>\n\t\t<\/div><\/div><div id=\"output-box-2969-212430\" class=\"buyer-note-output-box\"><\/div><\/div>"}}
```

Comment: so don't try parsing the json. LOOK at the json, and see what php error/warning is being dumped out to cause the parse error. `{"foo":"bar"}` is valid json. `PHP Warning: blah blahblah{"foo":"bar"}` isn't valid at all.

Comment: Use `try/catch` around the call to `JSON.parse()`. If it gets an error, it means there was an error logged before the JSON.

Comment: I found what was causing the JSON error, I had an extra array element that I was passing to the view parser. But I'm still wondering why the PHP logging call let it work.